# How to use watermark on all the print pages?

Tags: visualforce, html, images, table

I have html table on a visualforce page which is printed using window.print() javscript function.
This data on this table is printed on multiple pages depending upon it's record numbers.
I want to print a watermark image on the printed pages. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS and a image

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">

                .watermark {
                    background-repeat: repeat;
                    background-image: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.tran_watermark)}");
                }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="watermark">
        <!-- PDF stuff goes here -->
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

`background-repeat` will repeat the image and `media="print"` will only work when this page is available as PDF or in Print view.

Comment: I'm not using renderAs="pdf", instead using window.print() in javascript on vf page.

Comment: @JiteshGoel approach will be same. Did you try this solution?